# How to index into a pandas multindex with ix

Tags: python, pandas

I have setup some code like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
arrays = [['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux'],
          ['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two'],
          ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'eee', 'eee', 'eee' ]]
tuples = zip(*arrays)
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['A', 'B', 'C'])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4), index=index)

df
Out[161]: 
                    0         1         2         3
A   B   C                                          
bar one aaa  0.682220 -0.598889 -0.600635 -0.488069
    two bbb -0.134557  1.614224 -0.191303  0.073813
baz one ccc -1.006877 -0.137264 -0.319274  1.465952
    two ccc  0.107222  0.358468  0.165108 -0.258715
foo one ddd  0.360562  1.759095 -1.385394 -0.646850
    two eee -1.113520  0.221483  2.226704 -0.994636
qux one eee -0.609271 -0.888330  0.824189  1.772536
    two eee -0.008346 -0.688091  0.263303  1.242485
```

I want find matching rows based on combinations of criteria with the groups A, B and C.

e.g. in sql terms: select * where A in ('foo', 'qux') and C='eee'

Can I acheive this with ix? e.g. something like:

```
df.ix(['foo', 'qux'],:,'eee')
```

What is the idomatic way of achieving this for very large datasets?

(I'm currently using pandas 0.7 but can upgrade if absolutely necessary)

Comment: This breaks my head.... the closest I can get is `df.ix['foo':'qux'].xs('eee', level='C')`

Comment: ...or maybe `df.ix[['foo','qux']].xs('eee', level='C')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As of Pandas 0.14](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#multiindexing-using-slicers), you can pass a tuple of selectors to `df.loc` to slice a MultiIndex:

```
In [782]: df.loc[(['foo','qux'], slice(None), 'eee'), :]
Out[782]: 
                    0         1         2         3
A   B   C                                          
foo two eee  1.615853 -1.327626  0.772608 -0.406398
qux one eee  0.472890  0.746417  0.095389 -1.446869
    two eee  0.711915  0.228739  1.763126  0.558106
```

Answer (score 5):

I will write a function to do this kind of thing generically:

```
import numpy as np
def ms(df, *args):
    idx = df.index
    for i, values in enumerate(args):
        if values is not None:
            if np.isscalar(values):
                values = [values]
            idx = idx.reindex(values, level=i)[0]
    return df.ix[idx]
```

Then you can do it very easily:

```
ms(df, ['foo', 'qux'], None, "eee")
```

Comment: This is really great. Thank you. What does `ms` stand for? How do you feel about changing `if not isinstance(values, (tuple, list))` to `if isinstance(values, basestring)`?

Comment: `ms` is `MultIndexSelect`. Because values in Index maybe be int, float or datetime, it't not generically to check basestring only. I think it's better to use `not isinstance(values, collections.Iterable)`, since Pandas can convert iterable objects to Index.

Comment: Since str is also Iterable, I changed it to use `numpy.isscalar(values)`

Comment: In this case is using reindex equivalent to using xs?

Comment: How do you feel about `return df.reindex(idx)` instead of `return df.ix[idx]`?

Comment: This was proposed almost a year ago. Is there any reason why it didnt enter the official pandas? seems like very idiomatic usage.