# selection with hierarchical index - getting subset of the dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe which represent a matrix. it is indexed by row number and column number, something like that:

```
arrays = [[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3],[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]]
tuples = zip(*arrays)
index = MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['row', 'col'])
df = DataFrame([100,99,98,97,96,95,94,93,92],index,columns=['score'])


score
row col 
1   1    100
    2    99
    3    98
2   1    97
    2    96
    3    95
3   1    94
    2    93
    3    92
```

Now I'm trying to figure out how to select only cols 1 and 3 of row 1, meaning some code that will return:

```
score
row col 
1   1    100
    3    98
```

of course Im not looking for a code that explicitly selects 1 and 3, but rather the more general case, in which i will pass a list of level 0 indices and a list of level 1 indices, and will get back the appropriate subset.

I've tried:

```
k1 = 1
k2 = [1,3]
df.ix[k1,k2]
```

Which raise an error.

This does works:

```
df.ix[k1].ix[k2]
```

But only if k1 is scalar. if `k1=[1,3]` the proper subset is not retrieved, because the return dataframe is still indexed with level 0 index.

It deosnt look like what the author intended.. I see no reason why `df.ix[k1,k2]` (where k1 and k2 are scalars or vectors or a mix) shouldn't work. Am I missing something?

Comment: Representing a matrix as a multiindex DataFrame is kinda strange, what use case do you have in mind? Is it for representing a sparse matrix? If so wouldn't it be better to use scipy.sparse instead?

Comment: Well, it is an indexed matrix. it not rows vs cols as I showed here, but actually person vs. person. so for example the score of "john smith" on "jacob green" of some system is 50. what im trying to say is that my indexes are strings and not integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about `reindex()`?

```
df.reindex([1,2], level=0).reindex([1,3], level=1)
```

For a more general solution, here is a similar question I answered before:

[How to index into a pandas multindex with ix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15520408/how-to-index-into-a-pandas-multindex-with-ix)

I copy the code here:

```
import numpy as np
def ms(df, *args):
    idx = df.index
    for i, values in enumerate(args):
        if values is not None:
            if np.isscalar(values):
                values = [values]
            idx = idx.reindex(values, level=i)[0]
    return df.ix[idx]

ms(df, [1,2], [1, 3])
```

But I think `unstack()` the matrix is better:

```
m = df.score.unstack()
m.loc[[1,2],[1,3]]
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the why to go. but I stumbled into a different problem using it... see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21255234/memory-violation-when-using-dataframae-re-indexing)