# dataframe re-indexing object unnecessarily preserved in memory

Tags: python, pandas, ipython, jupyter-notebook

In continuation from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21234279/selection-with-hierarchical-index-getting-subset-of-the-dataframe) I've implemented 2 functions doing the same thing, one is using re-indexing and the other does not. the functions differ in the 3rd line:

```
def update(centroid):
    best_mean_dist = 200
    clust_members = members_by_centeriod[centroid]
    for member in clust_members:
        member_mean_dist = 100 - df.ix[member].ix[clust_members].score.mean()

        if member_mean_dist<best_mean_dist:
            best_mean_dist = member_mean_dist
            centroid = member
    return centroid,best_mean_dist

def update1(centroid):
    best_mean_dist = 200
    members_in_clust = members_by_centeriod[centroid]
    new_df = df.reindex(members_in_clust, level=0).reindex(members_in_clust, level=1)
    for member in members_in_clust:
        member_mean_dist = 100 - new_df.ix[member].ix[members_in_clust].score.mean()        

        if member_mean_dist<best_mean_dist:
            best_mean_dist = member_mean_dist
            centroid = member
    return centroid,best_mean_dist
```

The functions are being called from an IPython notebook cell:

```
for centroid in centroids:
    centroid = [update(centroid) for centroid in centroids]
```

The dataframe `df` is a large dataframe, with around 4 million rows and takes ~300MB in memory.

The `update1` function using re-indexing is much faster. but, something unexpected happens - after just a few iterations when running the one with re-indexing the memory quickly goes up from ~300MB to 1.5GB and then I get memory violation.

The `update` function does not suffer from this kind of behavior. 2 things I'm not getting:

1. re-indexing makes a copy, that is obvious. but isn't that copy suppose to die each time the update1 function is finished? the `newdf` variable should die with the function creating it.. right?
2. Even if the garbage collector is not killing `newdf` right away, one memory runs out, it should kill it and not raise outOfMemory Exception, right?
3. I tried killing df manually be adding `del newdf` at the end of the update1 function, that didn't help. so might that indicate that the bug is actually in the re-indexing process itself?

**EDIT:**

I found the problem, but I cant understand what is the reason for this behavior. It is the python garbage collector, refusing to clean the reindexed dataframe. 
This is valid:

```
for i in range(2000):
   new_df = df.reindex(clust_members, level=0).reindex(clust_members, level=1)
```

This is valid, too:

```
def reindex():
    new_df = df.reindex(clust_members, level=0).reindex(clust_members, level=1)
    score  = 100 - new_df.ix[member].ix[clust_members].score.mean()
    return score

for i in range(2000):
    reindex()
```

**This causes re-indexing object preservation in memory:**

```
z = []    
for i in range(2000):
    z.append(reindex())
```

I think my usage is naively correct. how does the `newdf` variable stay connected to the score value, and why?

Comment: pls put your python and pandas versions up; you are running 64-but right? you have at least 4gb right?

Comment: running pandas '0.12.0' 32 bit with 8GB memory. but it doesnt seem to be the re indexing that causing the problem. see my comment below..

Comment: 32 bit is limited to 2GB of actual space and 4GB of total memory (the extra memory doesn't do anything); in practice you will have a hard time allocated > 1GB (as generally python needs a contiguous space). You will have much better success on 64-bit

Comment: I found the problem and  edited the question (bottom), your thoughts will be highly appriciated

Comment: regarding your update: you are creating a new object each time, since you are holding a reference to each one, your memory will grow without bound.

Comment: I'm assigning a float variable (score) calculated from the new object. why is it considered to be a refernce to the object? as I see it, it shouldnt.

Comment: what you are doing is very odd; you should be grouping by cluster_members, then doing your calculation, would be much simpler and faster too

Comment: It is an iterative process. the cluster_members list is changing between iterations. so grouping by it once will not work. grouping by it each time seems to me less fast then indexing and reindexing. I can try to groupby in each iteration, but my intuition is that it would be slower. correct me if im wrong. And, BTW, now that i think of it, how do you group by a list? I can group by memberID attribute, but how do I select the proper group?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my debug code, when you do indexing, Index object will create `_tuples` and `engine map`, I think the memory is used by this two cache object. If I add the lines marked by `****`, then the memory increase is very small, about 6M on my PC:

```
import pandas as pd
print pd.__version__
import numpy as np
import psutil
import os
import gc

def get_memory():
    pid = os.getpid()
    p = psutil.Process(pid)
    return p.get_memory_info().rss

def get_object_ids():
    return set(id(obj) for obj in gc.get_objects())

m1 = get_memory()

n = 2000
iy, ix = np.indices((n, n))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([iy.ravel(), ix.ravel()])
values = np.random.rand(n*n, 3)
df = pd.DataFrame(values, index=index, columns=["a","b","c"])

ix = np.unique(np.random.randint(0, n, 500))
iy = np.unique(np.random.randint(0, n, 500))

m2 = get_memory()
objs1 = get_object_ids()

z = []
for i in range(5):
    df2 = df.reindex(ix, level=0).reindex(iy, level=1)
    z.append(df2.mean().mean())
df.index._tuples = None    # ****
df.index._cleanup()        # ****
del df2
gc.collect()               # ****
m3 = get_memory()

print (m2-m1)/1e6, (m3-m2)/1e6

from collections import Counter

counter = Counter()
for obj in gc.get_objects():
    if id(obj) not in objs1:
        typename = type(obj).__name__
        counter[typename] += 1
print counter
```

Comment: This code does not create memory leaks. also my reidnexing, using loops, does not create memory leak. It is also not a an ipython notebook problem, since running the code in WING also causes memory leak. So it has to be something with my usage or python garbage collector. Im looking in to it, will appreciate advises.

Comment: I found the problem and  edited the question (bottom), your thoughts will be highly appriciated

Comment: Thanks, i'll try it out and let you know. But do you have any insights regarding why does the dataframe in not being cleaned by the garbage collector?